# SQL INNER JOIN error - Can't join two tables: "There was a problem fetching the schema of the table. Try again."

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I have the following request on POSTGRESQL. I don't know where it comes from, but each time I run a join query I get an error: "There was a problem fetching the schema of the table. Try again."

**Context:**
I'm trying to get a table of sessions using subqueries from a DB named `sheets_app.tracks`; I then reuse this subquery in a new table to map users to sessions.

**This join is very simple but still doesn't work:**

```
WITH sessions as (
SELECT
    user_id || '-' || row_number() over(partition by user_id order by event_timestamp) as session_id
  , user_id
  , event_timestamp as session_start_at
  , lead(event_timestamp) over(partition by user_id order by event_timestamp) as next_session_start_at
FROM ( 
    SELECT
      user_id
        ,   event_timestamp
        , last_event_timestamp
        , (event_timestamp-last_event_timestamp) as inactivity_time
    FROM (
        SELECT
            user_id
            , event_timestamp
            , LAG(event_timestamp) over (PARTITION BY user_id order by timestamp) as last_event_timestamp
        FROM (
            SELECT
                user_id
                , timestamp
                , EXTRACT("EPOCH" FROM timestamp) as event_timestamp
                
            FROM
                sheets_app.tracks as e
        ) one
    ) two
) event
WHERE (event.inactivity_time > 30 OR event.inactivity_time is null))


SELECT 
    *       
FROM sessions
LEFT JOIN sheets_app.tracks on sessions.user_id = sheets_app.tracks.user_id
```

**This one is the same with more conditions on the LEFT JOIN**

```
WITH sessions as (
SELECT
    user_id || '-' || row_number() over(partition by user_id order by event_timestamp) as session_id
  , user_id
  , event_timestamp as session_start_at
  , lead(event_timestamp) over(partition by user_id order by event_timestamp) as next_session_start_at
FROM ( 
    SELECT
      user_id
        ,   event_timestamp
        , last_event_timestamp
        , (event_timestamp-last_event_timestamp) as inactivity_time
    FROM (
        SELECT
            user_id
            , event_timestamp
            , LAG(event_timestamp) over (PARTITION BY user_id order by timestamp) as last_event_timestamp
        FROM (
            SELECT
                user_id
                , timestamp
                , EXTRACT("EPOCH" FROM timestamp) as event_timestamp
                
            FROM
                sheets_app.tracks as e
        ) one
    ) two
) event
WHERE (event.inactivity_time > 30 OR event.inactivity_time is null))


SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS sessions_count,
  AVG(duration) AS average_session_duration
FROM (
  SELECT 
        session_id
        , (EXTRACT("EPOCH" FROM MIN(events.timestamp))-EXTRACT("EPOCH" FROM MAX(events.timestamp))) AS duration
  FROM sessions
  LEFT JOIN sheets_app.tracks as event on sessions.user_id = event.user_id
        AND EXTRACT("EPOCH" FROM events.timestamp) >= sessions.session_start_at
        AND EXTRACT("EPOCH" FROM events.timestamp) < sessions.next_session_start_at OR sessions.next_session_start_at is null) 
  GROUP BY 1
    ) as events
```

Do you see where it could come from?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that's a Postgres error message. Which tool do you use to run those queries?

Comment: Just a suggestion but your code would be much more readable, and easier to debug, if you had 1 CTE per SELECT statement rather than 1 CTE with all those SELECT statements buried in it

Comment: I've run it on pgAdmin and I have a "Waiting for the Query to complete" that doesn't end @a_horse_with_no_name